# Tabbed Form... html, java/jquery with CSS if needed

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, tabs

Hi i am after making a form with 12 different tabs and need the form to only submit the filled out form after clicking on an icon to activate that particular form...

EG:

load page->

click tab 2

then it loads row of icons and once you click on one of them the input fields below become active..  if you then change tab to eg tab 1 and click on one of them icons then the fields filled out on tab 2 now become inactive and do not submit with the submit button.

Comment: Could you post what you have tried? Maybe a jsFiddle with what you have so far.

Comment: You can make 12 forms, one form in each tab and upon filling the fields of a particular form you can add that for Id to an array. Finally upon clicking the icon you can submit the forms in the filled form array. Would have helped more if you had posted the code you have tried.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for a wizard flow

This might be helpfull to you

http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/wizard.html